# Return value with async function

Tags: node.js, callback, async.js

Right now I have a piece of code which makes two http requests in parallel.

```
var request = require('request');
var async = require('async');
var fs = require('fs');

module.exports = {
    req : function(options) {
        //populate list with 2 lookups
        var lookup_list = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            if(i == 1) {
                options.timeout = 200;
            }
            lookup_list.push(options);
        }
        //iterate through list with and do request calls
         async.map(lookup_list, function(options, next) {
            request(options, function (error, response, body) {
                if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                    var body = JSON.parse(body);
                    next(null, body);
                } else {
                    next(error || response.statusCode);
                }
            });
            //after both requests are finished, deal with responses
        }, function(err, results) {
            if (!err) {
                console.log(results);
                /*
                 fs.appendFile('log.txt', JSON.stringify(results[1]) + "\n",function callback(error){
                 if (error) {
                 return console.error('write failed: ', error);
                 }
                 });
                 */
            } else {
                console.error('request failed: ', err);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I want a to return the array results from the async.map callback when parallel.req() is called.

I've tried to provide a callback for req() and have it be called in the callback for async.map but no luck. I also tried other returns and callbacks elsewhere but have had no success. I would like some guidance to resolve this issue.

Comment: Check what a promise is. But you can't return data from async call. Before the data are loaded the return is "fired" (return isn't an event), and you got your return undefined.

Comment: yeah, I understood that any return I include won't provide the value I'm looking for as the rest my code (outside this module) will be executed meanwhile. I'll look into promises

Comment: In your case the req() function will return a promise and use the req().then() function to set data anywhere in your app.